# Should I trim spaces in passwords?

Tags: password

The problem is that we send a user an email with a generated password if they forget.

If they choose to cut and paste it in, then Outlook typically adds a " " to the end of it.

When they paste it into the password textbox, it breaks for them.

Should I just make it invalid to put spaces in a password and trim all passwords?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Don't trim spaces**, since some users do include spaces in their passwords.

**Don't email a generated password**. Instead send them a URL with an embedded one-time token, that takes them to a password reset screen.

**If you really must send a password** through email, note that Outlook only adds the space if there is a space after the word. For example, if you double-click the password below you'll get a space:

```
The password is here
```

But if you double-click the password below you won't get a space:

```
This is the password
```

So make sure the password is the last word on its line in the email, and the problem should go away.

Comment: Or alternatively, require that passwords don't have spaces. Whitespace should be part of any "illegal characters".

Comment: I don't think that any characters should be illegal for a password. It pretty much guarantees that you will introduce a usability issue if you do for someone. It also just encourages people to use "easy" passwords.

Comment: @Bennett : you're a legend! the no space ending thing worked. I will give you the top answer for that

Comment: @phinetune : what usability issue will you create by not allowing the user to use space? Also, it's just one character, they still have all the other special characters to use too.

Comment: @RoboShop spaces in passwords make them more secure as it will take a lot more time to crack them.

Comment: If you trim spaces (at beginning and end) when people sign up and when they sign in, nobody will notice.

Comment: That advice about the password being the last on a line is sound, but the "problem" then only goes away if you **do** trim leading and trailing spaces from any password entered.

Comment: @RoboShop: Suppose I have a a few different passwords, each for a certain security priority (e.g. One for banking, one for forums, etc.).  If you reject _any_ characters, you might reject one of my standard passwords, which irritates me and encourages me to pick something weak (that I still won't remember).  I hate using sites/software that put arbitrary restrictions on passwords.

Comment: @Bennett McElwee -- In my opinion, you MUST trim leading and trailing spaces, either at the client or at the server. Otherwise some users will be mighty pissed. Internal spaces are fine, of course, but there must be a printable graphic at either end.

Comment: @RoboShop: What @Steve S said. The usability issue comes about when the user has to process the error that results and on top of that inconvenience has to, on the spot, think of another password. Both of these things are annoying and unnecessary.

Comment: If a password is never displayed as plaintext (in the app or in an email) then there is no reason ever to trim it. If you want to trim it, you should come up with a good reason. **But there is no good reason.**

Comment: I prefer to always trim whitespace from beginning and end of passwords (never within password). This avoids issues with arbitrary whitespace being introduced due to users who copy and paste. Even though I never store or display the password in plain text, users often do. Even though users can reset their own passwords, the arbitrary whitespace issue still causes increased customer support emails.

Answer (score 7):

1. Try password they entered without trimming.
2. If it fails, and it has spaces, silently try it with trimming.

This allows people to use spaces if they wish, but doesn't punish people for accidentally including them.

We used to have a password entry where spaces were not trimmed.  We've found that even if you don't send password emails, you still get errors like this there because people write their passwords down in text files, and then cut & paste them.  Should they do that? Probably not, but you can't change that.

Comment: I almost agree with this. But then again it's up to the user to remember exactly what they typed. And seeing as password re-use runs rampant, it should not be a real issue for most people. But still, it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically to your question, you could define the requirement that passwords do not contain spaces at the beginning or the end, but still allow spaces in the middle. This would enable you to trim the supplied password (left trim, right trim), but still enable users to submit pass-phrases.

On a more general note, if it is within your ability to change, you might consider not sending passwords in an email. Other recovery techniques including security questions, password hints (defined by the user of course), or reset links would allow the user to recover/reset their password without actually sending them the password itself. This would eliminate the need for the user to copy-paste the password, and it might benefit the overall security of your system.

Comment: I have the reset password as a link in the email as well. This is just kind of in case they want to know the temp password, which a case could be made that there is no need for that...